# test promise reject case using mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I want to make test case for promise reject case.

Here is my code

1) File: TemplateFinder.js

```
**I want to make test for this method on promise reject using *mocha* how can i achieve this?**

var findTemplate = function (template) {

    return templateFinder.find(templateName)
        .then( (result) => {
            return result.id;
        });
};
```

2) query.js

```
var find = function (template) {
    return knex.where({
        internal_name: template,
    })
    .select('external_id')
    .from('mailing_external_template')
    .then(function (data) {
        if (0 === data.length) {
            return Promise.reject(RangeError('no result for id'));
        } else {
            return data[0].external_id;
        }
    });
};
```

3) app.js

```
Main file to run

function findTemplate()
{
    templateFinder.findGoodTemplate('good-mail-template');
}

initiateProcess()
.then(function (fromResolve) {
    return findTemplate();
})
.catch(function (e) {

});
```

My try:

```
it('should throw error if template not found', function () {

    var findTemplateIdStub = sinon.stub(templateFinder, 'find');

    var error = 'my expected error message returned by my function';
    findTemplateIdStub.returns(Promise.reject(error));

    return templateFinder.findTemplate(templateName)
      .catch(function(err) {
        assert.equal(err, error);
      });
  });
```

the problem with my try is findTemplate has no catch so how can i am asserting variables from my test case, not original. (Catch is not in code but still my test pass.)  Please help me to make test case for findTemplate reject case.

Answer (score 0):

Is `findTemplateIdStub`supposed to return a promise?

If that's the case, you can include [sinon-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised)  and the stub should be:

`findTemplateIdStub.rejects('some error')`  for the bad case

`findTemplateIdStub.resolves(1234)` for the good case